# Questions about making compiler for cool language in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

About a week ago I have started a online course "compilers" at coursera.org. Today I got some code for begining.

I was hoping you could help me to get answers to some questions.

`%{ /* some code */ %}`  => what is this, I always thinked that % is module operator

`[ \t]+`
`[0-9]+ { return(NUM); }` => I can understand `[0-9]+` part of code but I dont understand what `[\t]+` is doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like Lex, not C++

`%{ %}` specifies C/C++ code that will be copied verbatim into the output source.

`[ \t]+` ignores all blanks and tabs (`\t` is tab).

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right this is Lex to be more precise it is flex.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would have been great if the details of the language that the compiler is being written for, were provided.

From whatever information that has been provided, the best guess here is that the [\t] is for identifying tabs incase the of a python like language that uses indentation for identifying separate blocks of code.